# How to make a distance matrix from distance measurements from a loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, matrix, distance

I have a list `signatures`, and I loop through all the combinations in that list. 
Then, I calculate the distance between the combinations:

```
for (signature_combination in combn(signatures,2, simplify=FALSE))
   score(signature_combination[[1]],signature_combination[[2]])
   name1 <- signature_combination[[1]]$name
   name2 <- signature_combination[[2]]$name
}
```

`name1` and `name2` are the names of the signatures to compare, which are the row and column names in the distance matrix.

Now I want to add this to a dataframe so that I get a distance matrix.
I know the 3 ways of adding to a dataframe mentioned here: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-June/107734.html. However, this assumes that the values for the whole row are already known, but I only have 1 value per each time that I loop through, and they are not in order.

How can I add these values to a dataframe so that I get a distance matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using a loop in the first place? I'd use `expand.grid` and `by` to do the job:

```
comb = expand.grid(names(signature), names(signature))   # I fixed this line!
scores = by(comb,list(comb$Var1,comb$Var2), FUN=function(x) score(signature[[x[[1]]]],signature[[x[[2]]]]))
class(scores)="matrix"
scores
```

Comment: `comb$Var2` is `NULL`, so that doesn't work. If I change `comb$Var2` to `comb$Var1` I get `subscript out of bounds` error

Comment: Sorry. I had an error in the first line. I fixed it.